# Is there a way to make this Ruby ternary operation evaluate properly?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

The following line of code

```
<% invite.accepted ? { @going, @not_going = 'selected', '' } : { @going, @not_going = '', 'selected' } %>
```

is my attempt at condensing several operations (evaluating an expression and setting the values of two variables accordingly) into a single line.

It kicks up an error, claiming there's an unexpected comma.

Is there a way to make this work, or am I just overloading the poor ternary operator?

(This was just a personal experiment, by the way. I don't mind using a simple -- albeit cumbersome -- if/else statement)

EDIT: The following line of code works! I'll check off the proper answer as soon as I can!

```
<% invite.accepted ? ( @going, @not_going = 'selected', '' ) : ( @going, @not_going = '', 'selected' ) %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
@going, @not_going = invite.accepted ? ['selected', ''] : ['', 'selected']
```

`w, x = y, z` is the same as `w, x = [y, z]`, so this works just fine and there is no repetition.

Comment: I don't know how to avoid the 'compact' but what about '@going, @not_going = ['selected', ''].send(invite.accepted ? :compact : :reverse)'

Comment: @oldergod, if one more line is acceptable: `tags = ['selected', '']; @going, @not_going = invite.accepted ? tags : tags.reverse`

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be assigning `true` to `invite.accepted` instead of testing for it, try this:

```
<% (invite.accepted == true) ? (@coming, @not_coming = 'coming', '') : (@going, @not_going = 'not coming', 'selected') %>
```

This would be better since you don't need to test if `true == true`:

```
<% (invite.accepted) ? (@coming, @not_coming = 'coming', '') : (@going, @not_going = 'not coming', 'selected') %>
```

**Edit**

You could also try wrapping it in a function so it would evaluate to a single entity:

```
<% (invite.accepted) ? assign(@coming, @not_coming, 'coming', '') : assign(@going, @not_going, 'not coming', 'selected') %>

def assign(a,b,c,d)
   a, b = c,d;
end
```

Comment: If that were it, it at least should have allowed the `@going..` side of the block to be ignored. I think `?:` is not designed to handle this case.

Comment: Tried that, but had no luck. Thanks, though!

Comment: Yeah, sarnold, I'm starting to think that's the case.
It's honestly not a huge deal, just curious.

Comment: The only other suggestion I can think of is wrapping everything in parentheses. I have never seen a ternary operator like this.

Answer (score 1):

Parens *and* `;` work:

```
irb(main):018:0> foo = true ? (a=:a ; b=:b) : :foo
=> :b
irb(main):019:0> a
=> :a
irb(main):020:0> b
=> :b
irb(main):021:0>
```

---

Note that `,` is not a statement separator:

```
irb(main):001:0> a=:a, b=:b
=> [:a, :b]
irb(main):002:0> a
=> [:a, :b]
irb(main):003:0> b
=> :b
irb(main):004:0>
```

A `;` is a statement separator:

```
irb(main):004:0> a=:a; b=:b
=> :b
irb(main):005:0> a
=> :a
irb(main):006:0> b
=> :b
irb(main):007:0>
```

But this does not immediately help you because the interpreter is not looking for a statement separator -- only the `:`:

```
irb(main):014:0> foo = true ? a=:a, b=:b : :foo
SyntaxError: (irb):14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ':'
foo = true ? a=:a, b=:b : :foo
...
```

Parens and `,` does not throw an error but it does not work as expected:

```
irb(main):021:0> foo = true ? (a=:a , b=:b) : :foo
=> [:a, :b]
irb(main):022:0> a
=> [:a, :b]
irb(main):023:0> b
=> :b
irb(main):024:0>
```

I expected `do .. end` to work, but that also fails:

```
irb(main):024:0> foo = true ? do a=:a ; b=:b end : :foo
SyntaxError: (irb):24: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do
foo = true ? do a=:a ; b=:b end : :foo
...
```

Comment: I'm reading the OP's example as akin to (`a, b` = `:a, :b`).  And it kinda seems like Ruby does too.  The comma isn't acting as a statement separator; it's creating lists/tuples/whatever.

Comment: @cHao: Ah! I wrote my answer based on [the first version of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6e2c519c-f89f-4c5b-b604-0e007e7e8b56/view-source), where it looked like the _goal_ was `invite.accepted = (@going, @not_going='','')` -- storing three values into `invite.accepted` and updating one variable in the process. Your interpretation -- borne out by newer edits -- is definitely cleaner. And [Matheus has a superb solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11218424/377270) with that interpretation of the problem. :)

Comment: why not use the literal `a=1 and b=2` statement. I am not a big fan of using semicolons.

Comment: @Jason: I thought clarity would be enhanced by `a=:a` and expecting each variable to have exactly its symbol as its value. When the variables don't have the corresponding symbol as their value, it is easy to spot they are wrong. Perhaps it'd feel like less punctuation if I removed the complicated `irb` prompts...